# Difference in hours between two dates on daylight saving time with VBA

Tags: vba, regional-settings

Last Sunday had 23 hours due to the daylight saving time change. As a result some of my daily calculations are incorrect because they are made with an assumption of 24 hours.

I cannot find the method to calculate those 23 hours (25 in the case of the winter time change).

Comment: Please show a [mre] of your calculations.

Comment: Very easy ? datediff("h",#03/27/22#,#03/28/22#)
 24

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you determine Daylight Savings Time in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130877/how-do-you-determine-daylight-savings-time-in-vba)

Comment: When requested to improve your post, please do so through the [Edit] button beneath the tags of your question. Also include expected and actual result. It might also be beneficial to indicate Excel version.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to solve it, it probably influences my poor English, I will continue working on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timezone function `BiasWindowsTimezone` in my project at *GitHub*:

[VBA.Timezone-Windows](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Timezone-Windows)

(module `WtziCore`) to obtain the bias values for the start and the end time taking DST in account. Then, add the bias values to both date values and calculate the difference in hours:

```vb
Public Function HoursNormal( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    ByVal Timezone As String) _
    As Long

    Dim Date1Normal As Date
    Dim Date2Normal As Date
    Dim Hours       As Long
    
    Date1Normal = DateAdd("n", BiasWindowsTimezone(Timezone, True, Date1), Date1)
    Date2Normal = DateAdd("n", BiasWindowsTimezone(Timezone, True, Date2), Date2)
    
    Hours = DateDiff("h", Date1Normal, Date2Normal)
    
    HoursNormal = Hours

End Function
```

The timezone must be the literal of yours as found in the *Windows Registry*, for example `W. Europe` (there is code as well to retrieve and list these), and using your Sunday date, you will get 23 hours:

```vb
Date1 = #2022-03-27 00:00#
Date2 = #2022-03-28 00:00#

? HoursNormal(Date1, Date2, "W. Europe")
 23
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns 23h for March 27th and 25h for Oct 30th dates of the time change.

```vb
Function HorasDia(datFecha As Date) As Byte
Dim OutlookApp As Object
On Error Resume Next

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
HorasDia = DateDiff("h", OutlookApp.TimeZones.ConvertTime(datFecha, OutlookApp.TimeZones.Item("W. Europe Standard Time"), OutlookApp.TimeZones.Item("UTC")), OutlookApp.TimeZones.ConvertTime(datFecha + 1, OutlookApp.TimeZones.Item("W. Europe Standard Time"), OutlookApp.TimeZones.Item("UTC")))

If Not OutlookApp Is Nothing Then Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).